# Error al guardar datos en firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Tengo una función que guarda que recibe como parametro un objeto JSON y lo desglosa en dos objetos nuevos:

```
function insertDB(result){

var identification = "cadena";


for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {

while(result[i].Identificacion != identification ){

  db.ref('Estudiantes/'+ result[i].people_code_id).set({
    nombre: result[i].Nombres,
    identificacion: result[i].Identificacion,
    programa : result[i].ProgramaMateria,
    direccion : result[i].DIRECCION,
    ciudad: result[i].CIUDAD,
    departamento: result[i].DEPARTAMENTO,
    telFijo: result[i].TelFijo,
    telMovil: result[i].TelMovil,
    peopleCode: result[i].people_code_id,
    correo: result[i].EMAIL,
  });
  identification = result[i].Identificacion;
}
}

var CodigoMateria = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {

  while(result[i].CodigoMateria != CodigoMateria){
    db.ref('Materias/'+ result[i].CodigoMateria).set({
      CodMateria : result[i].CodigoMateria,
      Nombre: result[i].NombreMateria,
      Facultad: result[i].Facultad,
      Semestre: result[i].Semestre
    });
    CodigoMateria = result[i].CodigoMateria;
  }
}
}
```

El problema es que solo guarda en la BD (FIREBASE) el primer objeto JSON (Estudiantes) y no genera el segundo, he probado los metodos por separado y ambos envian, pero al juntarlos para que se envien los dos objetos no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes errores en el **for**. Entiendo que los datos que envías tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
var datos = [
{
    Identificacion: "Cadena",
    CodigoMateria: 0,
    //...
},{
    Identificacion: "Cadena 2",
    CodigoMateria: 1,
    //...
}
]
```

El problema está en el recorrido del '**for**', comienzas en **i = 0** y debes recorrer hasta **i < result.length** y no **i <= result.length**

El for debería quedar así:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    //Aqui va tu codigo...
}
```